# How can I move a View that was created on the UI Thread using a different Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, view

So I have this view that moves throughout different views that I have. I tried moving it using a new `thread` but I got "Can't access View from a different thread than it was created on", so I was like, "whatever just move it to the main thread then". So, I currently have `runOnUiThread(this)` (The class implements Runnable).

Now, it says:

```
Skipped x frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I googled for a loophole and found that I can use a `Handler` to do this, which I was able to follow until it was talking about implementing a task. [They](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) used a task called `PhotoTask` and not knowing what it was or where it came from, I just got lost.

So can somebody either explain the `Task` or tell me another potential way around this?

Code that's causing the error (Note there are more `if` statements, but they're all the same on the inside as this one:

```
while (lackees[i].getTileX() < lackees[i].getDestX()
                            && lackees[i].getTileY() < lackees[i]
                                    .getDestY()) {
                        lackees[i].setTileX(lackees[i].getTileX() + 1);
                        lackees[i].setTileY(lackees[i].getTileY() + 1);
                        getTileAt(0, lackees[i].getTileX() - 1,
                                lackees[i].getTileY() - 1).removeView(
                                lackees[i]);
                        getTileAt(0, lackees[i].getTileX(),
                                lackees[i].getTileY()).addView(lackees[i]);
```

**Progress Update #1**:
    It seems that `wait()` is better to use then `Thread.sleep()` but I still get frames lost, just not as many.

Comment: Did you try the view.post() method ?

Comment: can you post the code that is causing the issue?

Comment: @Blackbelt check edits

Comment: @JayeshElamgodil wouldn't that be the same thing as runOnUiThread()? They both queue it for the Ui Thread

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Sorry about that.

Comment: THERE IS NO LOOPHOLE. What are you doing with this view? and how can it be split up / optimised to take less time

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.
What do you mean by "So I have this view that moves throughout different views that I have".

Handler are mainly used to communicate between 2 threads.

PhotoTask in given link is simply an object/model used to send message from 1 thread to another via Handler.

If you want to update a view, you need to do this in main/UI thread alone. If you want to do some UI update from a separate thread you need to inform the default UI thread handler by passing the operation to be done as a separate runnable instance via runOnUiThread/ view.post/ handler.post. 
I can clarify on how to use shared views without using any handler or thread if this is what you need.

Comment: I should have specified that I have a View that moves through Layouts, that is my bad. But the code that I posted also includes `removeView()` and `addView()` inside of it so I figured that would be enough. At the same time, this doesn't answer my question of how to use the handler. But shared views sounds like it might be a way to do this so if you wouldn't mind then could you clarify?